# Compare the column of inner select query

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, select

Let suppose I am getting following table from query.

```
2011-08-09 16:43:37.160   020102100037  74.9900
2011-08-09 16:43:37.177   020102100038  74.9900
2011-09-07 16:48:57.823   020102100037  75.9900
2011-09-07 16:48:57.823   020102100038  75.9900
2011-09-07 16:49:19.000   020102100037  80.0000
2011-09-07 16:49:19.000   020102100038  80.0000
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT productcode, price FROM ( 
    inner select statement ) AS t
```

Now I want to get codes(2nd column) having maximum date.In above table I shall get the result.

```
2011-08-09 16:43:37.160   020102100037  74.9900
2011-08-09 16:43:37.177   020102100038  74.9900
```

So I am trying this query.

```
SELECT productcode, price FROM (
    SELECT productcode, price FROM ( 
        inner select statement) AS c  
    WHERE date =
        (SELECT MAX(cast(date as datetime)) 
        FROM c WHERE productcode = c.productcode
```

But I am getting the error

**Invalid object name 'c'.**

*Can any body suggest me solution or any other alternative to perform this task.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`c` is not a table or a view, it's a derived table. You can't reuse it like that. If you want reuse, look up Common Table Expressions. And what's wrong with `GROUP BY`, or `SELECT TOP 1` or `ROW_NUMBER`, anyway? They're commonly used to solve these problems.

```
WITH cteProducts
     AS (SELECT ProductDate
                , ProductCode
                , ProductPrice
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductCode ORDER BY ProductDate DESC) RowNumber
           FROM Products)
SELECT *
  FROM cteProducts
 WHERE RowNumber = 1;
```